# Git commit without files or folder

Tags: git-commit

Git is telling me to commit some 10000 changes but here's the catch, I deleted the folder in which the files to commit are located. Any thoughts on how I can stop git from telling me this.

Comment: Did you check the `git status` after deleting the `folder` that contains `tracked changes`?

Answer (score 0):

Run `git reset --hard origin/<branch_name>` and the branch will realign with your origin counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `directory or files` to do not track by `git`

Run this command

`git update-index --assume-unchanged <directory> or <file>`

Answer (score 0):

If those files in the folder are don't need in repo, you may add the folder path into .gitignore file. then git won't ask again to commit changes.